# Creating an array, assigning a value to each indices, and assessing the array

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to create an unassigned array of size 512 and then assigning a reading to each indices. I want to get the start time before and after the loop and only run it once. Then I want to know how to retrieve the readings and serialprint the values after the loop. So far this is what I have but I don't think it is running as I want it to. I was able to get the start time but I'm not sure if it is running afterwards. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
void setup() { 
int Vs[512] = {}; 
int analogPin = A0; // turn pin A0 on 
pinMode(9, INPUT); 
Serial.begin(9600); // setup serial 
analogWrite(9, pow(2, 7)); //LED power 0 
int time = micros(); 
Serial.println(time); 
}

void loop() { 
int i; 
for (int i = 0; i <= 511; i++); { //loop setup for 512 
int c = analogRead(A0) * (5.000/1024.000); 
int Vs[i] = {c}; 
Serial.println(Vs[i]); 
} 
int stoptime = micros(); 
Serial.println(stoptime); 
}

void stop() { 
while(1); 
}
```

Comment: if you want to run the code only once, then put the code in the setup() block ... leave the loop() block empty

Comment: why do you have a stop() function? ... you never call it

Comment: make the array global. and it is too large for Uno. and `Vs[i] = analogRead(A0) * (5.000/1024.000); `

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your program. The most obvious is that,
if you define a variable multiple times, you end up with mutliple
*different* variables that share the same name. For example:

```cpp
void setup() { 
    int Vs[512] = {};  // this Vs is local to setup()
}

void loop() {
    int i;  // this i is local to loop()
    for (int i = 0;  // this other i is visible within the for loop only
            i <= 511;
            i++)
        ;  // this is the body of the for loop
    {
        ...
        int Vs[i] = {c};  // this Vs is local to loop()
    }
}
```

Another issue I pointed out in the snippet above is that a semicolon by
itself is an empty (i.e. do-nothing) statement. Thus you `for` loop is
empty.

There is no point in defining a constant such as `analogPin = A0` if you
don't use it.

The value returned by `micros()` is not an `int`, it's an
`unsigned log`.

If you store a voltage in volts in an `int`, you get a very poor
resolution of one volt. You could store in a `float`, but that would
fill up the memory of your Arduino. I would rather store the raw
readings, and convert to volts only for printing.

`Serial.println()` takes time, and you are doing this during the timed
part of your code, which is probably unintended.

Here is a version of your program that may better reflect your
intentions. It takes 512 analog readings, stores them in an array, then
prints them and reports the time taken to do the readings. Then it waits
for one second and repeats the whole thing again.

```cpp
const uint8_t analogPin = A0;
const int readings_count = 512;
int Vs[readings_count];

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // Take a run of analog readings.
    unsigned long start_time = micros();
    for (int i = 0; i < readings_count; i++) {
        Vs[i] = analogRead(analogPin);
    }
    unsigned long stop_time = micros();

    // Print the readings.
    Serial.println("Voltage readings:");
    for (int i = 0; i < readings_count; i++) {
        Serial.println(5.0/1024 * Vs[i]);
    }
    Serial.print("Data recorded in ");
    Serial.print(stop_time - start_time);
    Serial.println(" µs");
    Serial.println();

    // Wait before the next run.
    delay(1000);
}
```

If you really want to run only one iteration of the process, then you
can just replace `delay(1000);` by `exit(0);`. Alternatively, move the
body of `loop()` to the end of `setup()`, and keep an empty `loop()`.